# Restart a WCF Service on IIS via Silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight

Is there a built-in method to restart a WCF service that I can invoke from my client? I have a static constructor and also it would help me while I'm testing my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. That would be a serious security vulnerability, if someone could somehow restart your service from a non-administrator account (a SL client just sends the request to the service over HTTP, or a non-authenticated TCP socket in SL4).

You should be able to restart the service by recycling the application pool for the application. Touching web.config should do the trick (open the file in notepad, save it, even without any modifications).

Comment: If you restart the application (via the web.config), I think it should do that. If that doesn't work, you can always go to "iisreset".